# Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects - indexes are unique

Tags: python, pandas

I am attempting to concat two dataframes. When I tried doing so, I was hit with the error that the `Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects` while trying to run this code:
`df_3=pd.concat([df_1,df_2])`.

I have added the following checks and updates to try and identify the issue:

```
df_1= df_1.reset_index(drop=True)
df_2= df_2.reset_index(drop=True)
try:
    df_3=pd.concat([df_1,df_2], ignore_index=True)

except Exception as e:
    print(df_1.index.is_unique)
    print(df_1.index.to_list())
    print(df_2.index.is_unique)
    print(df_2.index.to_list())
    df_1.to_csv("../../df_1.csv")
    df_2.to_csv("../../df_2.csv")
    raise Exception(e)
```

This results in the following output:

```
True
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44,
 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50, 51, 52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57, 58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 68, 69, 70, 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76, 77, 78, 79, 80, 81, 82, 83, 84, 85, 86, 8
7, 88, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 120, 121, 122, 123,
 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131, 132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140]
True
[0, 1]
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

I do not know why this is occurring - I do not get the same issue when I am testing in a console. Please advise!

Comment: Can you `print(df_1.columns)` and  `print(df_2.columns)` ?

Comment: Working on it now - is there a reason the columns would create an error?

Comment: If you have duplicated columns names in at least one of the dataframes, you'll get an `InvalidIndexError`.

Comment: Indeed that was the issue! Not sure why they don't name it more aptly. Thank you!

Comment: If you answer it below, I'll mark it as the correct answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error was I has duplicate column names - two columns in one dataframe with the same value. Pandas throws the same error in that situation. Thank you to @Timeless for finding the issue!